# Two modals at the entrance to the site

Tags: popup, modal-windows, cookies

We design a global website, and it is important for us to inform the user which website he is on so that he can pick the country that suits him. As in the example of Apple:

[image]

Although from a regulatory standpoint, it's also necessary to have a cookie banner. We thought about how we could present both:

- Option A: Modal over modal. The attached example illustrates this.
- Option B: Modal after modal. A country model will appear after approving cookies.

[image]

Neither option is ideal for us. Modal is an exhausting and irritating tool. Do you think there is a way to present them together?

Thank you!

Comment: It seems like users would want to default to the site of the country that they’re in, with the option to switch. Can your website choose the default country based on IP address?

Comment: Please see my comment below. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Skip the country modal altogether** and inform the user of which site they're viewing through a small icon of a flag, and/or label (with the default set to the country of the detected IP address). Clicking on the flag would take the user to a place where they could change to another country. (Note that flag icons are for countries and not languages; languages should always use labels.) Here are some examples of country selectors:

[image: Example of a country selector with flags and labels]

[image: Ebay's example of a country selector for phone number prefixes]

The [scope of who GDPR protects](https://siteimprove.com/en/gdpr/who-gdpr-affects-and-whose-data-is-protected/) is so broad that it should be presented on all country sites if your company does business in the EU and collects personal data. The less-obtrusive pattern is to use a banner at the bottom (like you posted in your example).

Answer (score 0):

Given that your website must abide different rules ( ex: EU GDPR Notice ) a person should preferably be identified by country and redirected to the correct website or select it manually from your mldal and only afterwards presented with the cookie notice.

Comment: To meet everyone's needs, we will design the site to the highest standards.
If it reaches an internal page, we don't want to lead it straight to the local site, since then it will drop back to the home page.
Also, we don't want to create friction for users (a front page where they must pick a country) because sometimes they'll get enough information without moving to another country.
It's just a way to let them know what country they are in so they can switch if they wish.